# App launches and closes in ios for appium automation

Tags: java, xcode8, appium, appium-ios

Problem:
Successfully created WebDriver Agent in xcode,
When i try to run my code, the ios application launches and automatically gets closed.
Please help me with the solution.
Environment
Xcode version = 8.3.3
OSX 10.12.6
Appium version 1.6.4
simulator : iPhone SE 10.3
Successfully created webdriver agent in xcode, When i Run the Appium server, the ipa file (tried with .app file also) gets launched and automatically getting closed.
Below is my code

```
DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.IOS);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"10.3");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone SE");          
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID,
"813f6a5691bc091cb6653dc09176a107be
          108193");
    cap.setCapability("bundleId","com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev");         


    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,"/Users/testusers/Desktop/dynamite.ipa");
             IOSDriver driver = new driver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "100");
Appium logs
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.4
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {“desiredCapabilities”:{“automationName”:“XCUITest”,“bundleId”:“com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”,“platformName”:“iOS”,“deviceName”:“iPhone SE”,“platformVersion”:“10.3”}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{“automationName”:“XCUITest”,“bundleId”:“com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”,“platformName”:“iOS”,“deviceName”:“iPhone SE”,“platformVersion”:“10.3”},null,null,null,null]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘newSessionRequested’ logged at 1505558554236 (16:12:34 GMT+0530 (IST))
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.27.2) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium] automationName: ‘XCUITest’
[Appium] bundleId: ‘com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev’
[Appium] platformName: ‘iOS’
[Appium] deviceName: ‘iPhone SE’
[Appium] platformVersion: ‘10.3’
[debug] [XCUITest] XCUITestDriver version: 2.27.2
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 7f722999-3e44-4ab1-bb62-78c75d5b2fff
[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to ‘8.3.3’ (tools v8.3.2.0.1.1492020469)
[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to ‘10.3’
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘xcodeDetailsRetrieved’ logged at 1505558554921 (16:12:34 GMT+0530 (IST))
[iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 8.3.3 with udid ‘F53C801A-D1FD-48A5-9910-2776673DE3A5’
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: ‘F53C801A-D1FD-48A5-9910-2776673DE3A5’, real device: false
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘appConfigured’ logged at 1505558555750 (16:12:35 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘resetStarted’ logged at 1505558555751 (16:12:35 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Path must be a string. Received undefined
[XCUITest] Reset: could not scrub application with id “com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”. Leaving as is.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘resetComplete’ logged at 1505558555834 (16:12:35 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [iOSLog] Starting iOS 10.3 simulator log capture
[debug] [iOSLog] System log path: /Users/testuser/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/F53C801A-D1FD-48A5-9910-2776673DE3A5/system.log
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘logCaptureStarted’ logged at 1505558555983 (16:12:35 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Setting up simulator
[debug] [iOS] No reason to set locale
[debug] [iOS] No iOS / app preferences to set
[XCUITest] Simulator with udid ‘F53C801A-D1FD-48A5-9910-2776673DE3A5’ not booted. Booting up now
[debug] [iOSSim] Killing all iOS Simulators
[debug] [iOSSim] Simulator is not running. Continuing…
[iOSSim] Starting simulator with command: open -Fn /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app --args -CurrentDeviceUDID F53C801A-D1FD-48A5-9910-2776673DE3A5 -ConnectHardwareKeyboard 0
[iOSSim] Simulator booted in 46469ms
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘simStarted’ logged at 1505558602578 (16:13:22 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘appInstalled’ logged at 1505558602578 (16:13:22 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaStartAttempted’ logged at 1505558602580 (16:13:22 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Using WDA path: ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent’
[XCUITest] Using WDA agent: ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj’
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: ‘/usr/local/bin/carthage’
[debug] [XCUITest] Killing hanging processes
[debug] [XCUITest] Beginning test with command ‘xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination id=F53C801A-D1FD-48A5-9910-2776673DE3A5 -configuration Debug IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3’ in directory ‘/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent’
[debug] [XCUITest] Output from xcodebuild will not be logged
[debug] [XCUITest] Waiting up to 60000ms for WebDriverAgent to start
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [XCUITest] Log file for xcodebuild test: /Users/testuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/F9620691-B4F7-4971-B9A3-89863D0D8DDC/Session-WebDriverAgentRunner-2017-09-16_161331-UuT3NR.log
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: “{\n “value” : {\n “state” : “success”,\n “os” : {\n “name” : “iOS”,\n “version” : “10.3.1”\n },\n “ios” : {\n “simulatorVersion” : “10.3.1”,\n “ip” : “192.168.1.104”\n },\n “build” : {\n “time” : “Sep 12 2017 12:04:15”\n }\n },\n “sessionId” : “202DD193-C28A-49BC-AE97-549CE8741456”,\n “status” : 0\n}”
[debug] [XCUITest] WebDriverAgent running on ip ‘192.168.1.104’
[debug] [XCUITest] WebDriverAgent successfully started after 16949ms
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1505558619664 (16:13:39 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {“desiredCapabilities”:{“bundleId”:“com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”,“arguments”:[],“environment”:{},“shouldWaitForQuiescence”:true,“shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection”:false,“maxTypingFrequency”:60,“shouldUseSingletonTestManager”:true}}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {“value”:“Failed to launch com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev application”,“sessionId”:“202DD193-C28A-49BC-AE97-549CE8741456”,“status”:13}
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1505558862184 (16:17:42 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {“desiredCapabilities”:{“bundleId”:“com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”,“arguments”:[],“environment”:{},“shouldWaitForQuiescence”:true,“shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection”:false,“maxTypingFrequency”:60,“shouldUseSingletonTestManager”:true}}
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {“value”:“Failed to launch com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev application”,“sessionId”:“202DD193-C28A-49BC-AE97-549CE8741456”,“status”:13}
[debug] [XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying…
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘wdaSessionAttempted’ logged at 1505559102153 (16:21:42 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {“desiredCapabilities”:{“bundleId”:“com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”,“arguments”:[],“environment”:{},“shouldWaitForQuiescence”:true,“shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection”:false,“maxTypingFrequency”:60,“shouldUseSingletonTestManager”:true}}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session - - ms - -
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {“desiredCapabilities”:{“automationName”:“XCUITest”,“bundleId”:“com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”,“platformName”:“iOS”,“deviceName”:“iPhone SE”,“platformVersion”:“10.3”}}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{“automationName”:“XCUITest”,“bundleId”:“com.dynamiteclothing.loyalty.dev”,“platformName”:“iOS”,“deviceName”:“iPhone SE”,“platformVersion”:“10.3”},null,null,null,null]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event ‘newSessionRequested’ logged at 1505559153667 (16:22:33 GMT+0530 (IST))
```

Comment: What happens, when you drag manually the .app file to the simulator and manually launch it? Does it still get closed? This appears not an appium issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps me

In iOS You need to have the app with debug permissions. Contact your development team to provide you build with debug permissions.

AppName.app (for simulator) and AppName.ipa (for iphone/ipad physical device) are the two files needed and created using Xcode IDE. You need to build the app as DEBUG/RELEASE (in XCODE -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Select RUN on the left panel -> Select INFO on top menu bar -> To the right of Build Configuration toggle between Release (creates an IPA*) and (Debug creates an APP). COMMAND+B will build your project. After the build process completes navigate to DerivedData folder which can be found using this: (in XCODE -> File -> Workspace Settings -> click on small arrow to the right of file URL. The file URL is just above the "Advanced..." button.

See XCODE (Window -> Organizer -> Archives -> Export -> Adhoc to create the IPA file).

http://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-test-on-ios-opens-and-close-the-application-over-and-over-again/8390/11

Answer (score 0):

Seems your ipa file is not a debug enabled build. Check with your developer to get a debug enabled ipa file.